# How pass main table selected column value as sub query column name in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

Is there any way to pass selected table column value to a subquery?

As an example, I have a `Stock` table, it has some section stock simple A_Stock, B_Stock, C_Stock like...

```
| Item Code    | A_Stock  | B_Stock  | C_Stock 
+--------------+----------+----------+---------
| Item1        | 10       |  13      |   35    
| Item2        | 15       |  20      |   45    
| Item3        |  8       |   6      |   33
```

And I select ItemCode and Section (A, B...) from that table Like

```
SELECT ItemCode, Section  
FROM tableName

| Item Code    | Section  
+--------------+---------
| Item1        | A       
| Item3        | C       
| Item2        | B
```

Then I want to select Item wise Section stock

Expected result

```
SELECT
    ItemCode, 
    (SELECT CONCAT(ST.SectionFrom, '_Stock') firstTable 
     WHERE ItemCode = ST.ItemCode) AS Stock
FROM 
    secondTable ST

| Item Code     | Stock 
+---------------+-------
| Item1         |  10   
| Item3         |  33   
| Item2         |  20
```

But the actual result is:

```
| Item Code     | Stock    
+---------------+----------
| Item1         | A_Stock  
| Item3         | C_Stock  
| Item3         | B_Stock
```

If anyone has a solution please help me.

Comment: The real problem seems like you should be normalising your table. `Stock` should be 1 column, with another column denoting if it is for Stock `A`, `B` or `C`.

Answer (score 2):

You can join those tables and use a `case..when` expression :

```
SELECT ItemCode, 
       (case 
        when section = 'A' then A_Stock 
        when section = 'B' then B_Stock 
        when section = 'C' then C_Stock      
        end ) AS Stock
  FROM secondTable ST
  JOIN stock S
    ON S.ItemCode = ST.ItemCode
```

Comment: Thank you very much for help. There are 25 Sections in the stock table, so there are 25 statements in the case, and also have to select around 6000 item, is it possible to use a case statement

Comment: you're welcome @GeethMadhushan . Yes, possible but ugly :) study on Gordon's solution also.

Answer (score 2):

One approach to this is to unpivot the data and join:

```
select st.*, v.stock
from stocktable st cross apply
     (values ('A', a_stock), ('B', b_stock), ('C', c_stock)
     ) v(section, stock) join
     tablename t
     on t.item_code = st.item_code and t.section = v.section;
```

I like this solution because it hints at how you should actually be storing the data in the `stock` table.  In general, you don't want multiple columns just distinguished by numbers.  You want a table that has `itemcode`, `section`, and `stock` as three columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Here is a solution that is not preferred as it hard codes the column names.  
--DROP TABLE firsttable
CREATE TABLE firsttable
(
    [Item_Code] nvarchar(8)
    ,[A_Stock] int
    ,[B_Stock] int
    ,[C_Stock] int
)

--DROP TABLE secondtable
CREATE TABLE secondtable
(
    [Item_Code] nvarchar(8)
    ,[Section] nvarchar(1)
)

INSERT INTO firsttable ([Item_Code],[A_Stock],[B_Stock],[C_Stock])
    VALUES  ('Item1', 10, 13, 35)
    ,('Item2', 15, 20, 45)
    ,('Item3', 8, 6, 33)

SELECT * FROM firsttable

INSERT INTO secondtable ([Item_Code],[Section])
    VALUES  ('Item1', 'A')
    ,('Item2', 'B')
    ,('Item3', 'C')

SELECT  * FROM secondtable

SELECT f.Item_Code
,(  CASE 
    WHEN CONCAT(s.Section,'_Stock') = 'A_Stock'THEN A_Stock
    WHEN CONCAT(s.Section,'_Stock') = 'B_Stock' THEN B_Stock
    ELSE C_Stock
    END
)
AS Stock

FROM firsttable f, secondtable s
WHERE f.Item_Code = s.Item_Code
```